# Data grid view load overflow using mysql

Tags: c#, mysql, database, datagridview

Hy everyone i'd like to ask for help about loading datas into data grid view from mysql database and i get some errors! Here's my code for the load method

```
if(this.OpenConnection()==true)
        {
            mySqlDataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter("select * from adatok_omlesztett", connection);
            DataSet DS = new DataSet();
            mySqlDataAdapter.Fill(DS);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = DS.Tables[0];

            this.CloseConnection();

        }
```

and after that i got an error : "key not foundexception was unhandled"

From the database structure: its only on tabe wich contains 70 colums an 100 rows . but if i try with less datas the grid view shows the datas without any error. i think the problem is somwhere in the data set using.

Comment: Perhaps you could post your solution so others know how to deal with this matter too!

Comment: of course the problem was with the charset at the database. It was on utf 32 charset and i had to replace it into  utf 8 unicode it and after it did work !